# azure queue service php connectionstring

Tags: php, azure, queue

So I want a script to connect to a queue and retrieve messages. On a .NET application, I used the following string to connect and all worked well:

```
sb://host.com/USER;StsEndpoint=https://host.com:9355/USER/;RuntimePort=9354;ManagementPort=9355;SharedSecretIssuer=USER;SharedSecretValue=XXX';
```

It's a pretty big string but it worked well in .NET. For php however, I noticed in the Azure php sdk documentation, the connection string should have the following format:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=[http|https];AccountName=[yourAccount];AccountKey=[yourKey]
```

I'm not sure how to "translate" the large url I have in the format needed for php. I tried the following but didn't work

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https://host.com;AccountName=USER;AccountKey=XXX
```

Anyone know how the connection string should actually look like? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're mixing 2 things - Service Bus Queues in .Net and Azure Storage Queues in PHP. The connection string you are trying to use in PHP is for Storage Queues. Based on the documentation here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php (See "Getting Started" section), the connection string for Service Bus should be in this format:

> Endpoint=[yourEndpoint];SharedSecretIssuer=[yourWrapAuthenticationName];SharedSecretValue=[yourWrapPassword]
>
> Where the Endpoint is typically of the format
>   https://[yourNamespace].servicebus.windows.net.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great article showing how this should be setup:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-php-how-to-use-queues

> Endpoint=[yourEndpoint];SharedSecretIssuer=[Default Issuer];SharedSecretValue=[Default Key]

This article explains setting up an ACS connection which will be required when using via PHP:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-authentication-and-authorization